# Using minimal types with pointers to void

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When I get an argument from the command line, I should use that argument to determine the type of arrays, matrices and vectors. The idea is to forward to initializing functions an argument that is void* and then cast a type to a specific primitive type.

It should do something like this:

```
void initMatrix1D(void *mat, int c, int m, int arg){
    if(arg==200){
       (unsigned char*)mat;
       for(int j=0; j<c; j++){
           mat[j]=rand()%m;
       }
    }
    else if(arg==1000){
        for(int j=0; j<c; j++){
            (unsigned short*)mat[j]=rand()%m;
        }
    }
    else{
        cout<<"No existing type for "<<arg<<". Program will now close."<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Of course, this does not work. Can someone give me a hint on how to do it?

Comment: Have you considered using templates? Something like `template <typename T> initMatrix1D( std::vector<T>& mat....)`

Comment: If the goal is to get this to compile, then make it `((unsigned char*)mat)[j] = ...;` and `((unsigned short*)mat)[j] = ...;`

Comment: Showing the calling code may help to show what is wrong with the design.

Comment: I don't have the calling code. The text I've given to you is the text of the assignment and I don't even know how to start. The code I provided is only a test code, but it isn't a good idea.